# How can I run some calls to a site as Test

Tags: php, asp.net, vb.net

I need to run different consecutive calls to a web service with no particular response needed to be read, just need execution.

What is the simplest approach? I can run either asp.net or php script.

```
https://ws1/ws/ws.aspx?propid=10468&action=1&pwd=dsdgsdfgs
https://ws1/ws/ws.aspx?propid=1022&action=1&pwd=dsdgsdfgs
https://ws1/ws/ws.aspx?propid=4564&action=1&pwd=dsdgsdfgs
https://ws1/ws/ws.aspx?propid=104688&action=1&pwd=dsdgsdfgs
https://ws1/ws/ws.aspx?propid=11234&action=1&pwd=dsdgsdfgs
https://ws1/ws/ws.aspx?propid=5432&action=1&pwd=dsdgsdfgs
https://ws1/ws/ws.aspx?propid=23445&action=1&pwd=dsdgsdfgs
```

Comment: Basically need to make a call to the above links, nothing else.

Comment: What web server? IIS or apache? If the latter, then you should also have ab (the Apache workBench)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in PHP you would use the curl class to make requests to urls, and receive responses.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 1):

If using .NET, use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class to request URLs, and just ignore the responses.

```
Imports System.Net

Dim urls() As String = { "url1", "url2" }

Dim webClient As New WebClient()
For Each url in urls
    webClient.DownloadData(url)
Next
```

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'WebClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to import `System.Net`.